# Udacity Sunshine android app -- MainActivity.java incongruities -- SDK target error?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm following Udacity's Android programming course and implementing the Sunshine app.  It's pretty good and the implementation is a bit of a treasure hunt! I've been stuck for over 24 hours now and have tried everything so hoping for a bit of help in case I've missed something glaring!

Everything was going great until late in lesson 4b when it was time to make ForecastFragment implement LoaderCallbacks.  As soon as I added the *implement*, my MainActivity.java stopped wanting to compile with the constructor to ForecastFragment being underlined with the error that the arguments are wrong. First here is the declaration of the class I'm trying to instantiate (note that they insist the v4 support libraries are to be used:)

```
// ...
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
// ...
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment
        implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
```

Anyway, after much gnashing of teeth and researching I've found that the initial MainActivity.java that was generated is different than the one I should have had. Amazingly it's made no difference until now!

Here is the MainActivity.java that I'm ***supposed*** to have:

```
package com.mydomain.sunshine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

And here is one I ***actually*** had, generated when I created my project:

```
package com.mydomain.sunshine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here was my build.gradle at this point too:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydomain.sunshine"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
}
```

Okay, so to solve this compile error I made sure I had all the SDK stuff I needed installed correctly and changed the build.gradle to:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

And with that the correct MainActivity.java compiled and the project built fine and launched in my emulator, but now I'm getting the following run-time exception at launch:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.sunshine/com.mydomain.sunshine.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:108)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
            at com.mydomain.sunshine.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 18:21:46.854    2660-2660/com.mydomain.sunshine I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2660 SIG: 9
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your problem is with the `Theme` you're using. It seems the original lessons used the libraries for later APIs but now you've moved on to the static appcompat support libraries (hence using `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`). Check your `AndroidManifest` for what `Theme` the app is using and also the `Theme` for your `Activity`. The logcat line says it all... `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: Thank you very much that did the trick! On the other hand I have a different run time exception now but I reckon it's unrelated, unless "java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mydomain.sunshine.ForecastFragment.onCreate(ForecastFragment.java:111)" rings a bell with that line being         mForeCastAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
Thanks I'll keep digging!

Comment: If `mForeCastAdapter.setViewBinder` is throwing NPE it suggests `mForeCastAdapter` hasn't been initialized.

Answer (score 2):

simply add ActionBar Compat your activity or application should use @style/Theme.AppCompat theme in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
```

This will add actionbar in activity(or all activities if you added this theme to application)